# Center the HTML images

Tags: html, css

I want the two images being centered. See https://prnt.sc/qxaapc for a visual representation of what I want.

Code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  height: 28%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" align="center">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.row
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using floats you could better use flexbox. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for all the different options you have with this.

Working example:

```css
/* General */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Specific */
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  flex: 0 1 28%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Snow">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  </div>

</div>
```

Small tip: try to avoid inline styling like style="width: 100%" on the images.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this:**

```css
.column {
  width: 28%;
  height: 28%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't like code-only answers. Because you originally provide no explanation of what this code solves, it was flagged and put on a review queue to see if it should be deleted. Please edit your answer and add a comment so someone doesn't delete it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**class="column"** for the inner sections is causing the images to appear side-by-side.

These 2 changes can make the images appear one below the other, in a center justified manner:

1. Specify 'align=center' for the top level section.
2. Specify 'class=row' for the sections that show the images.

**Here is the working solution:**

```
<div align="center">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" alt="Snow" style="width:300px">
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" style="width:300px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  height: 28%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}
```

```html
<div class="row" align="center">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

I just set for .row `display: flex; justify-content:center;` style

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float:left` in your `.column` class
and use `width:100%` for `.row` class

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row{
width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28%;
  height: 28%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" align="center">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```